# How to include .tar.gz dependency in pip package?

Tags: python, pip, dependency-management, python-packaging, tar.gz

### Context

While publishing a pip package, I am experiencing some difficulties in including the `lava-nc` dependency in the form of a `.tar.gz` file. Suppose the package (here called `magic`) has a directory structure as follows:

```
snnalgocompare/
  src/
    snnalgocompare/
      __init__.py
  dependencies/
    lava-nc-v0.5.1.tar.gz
  setup.py
```

where the dependency can be installed with:

```
pip install https://github.com/a-t-0/lava/archive/refs/tags/v0.5.1.tar.gz
```

however, I prefer the pip package to be self-contained.

### Code

The `setup.py` file looks like this:

```py
"""Packaging logic for snnalgocompare."""
from __future__ import annotations

import os
import sys

import setuptools

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "src"))

setuptools.setup()
```

and the `setup.cfg` contains:

```
[metadata]
name = snnalgocompare
version = attr: snnalgocompare.__version__
description = compares snn algorithms against neumann algorithms
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
url = https://github.com/a-t-0/snnalgocompare
author = a-t-0
author_email = no-email@no-email.org
maintainer = a-t-0
maintainer_email = no-email@no-email.org
license = AGPLv3
license_file = licence
classifiers =
    Development Status :: 2 - Pre-Alpha
    Environment :: Console
    Intended Audience :: Science/Research
    License :: OSI Approved :: GNU Affero General Public License v3
    Programming Language :: Python
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.11
    Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Artificial Intelligence

[options]
packages = find:
package_dir =
    =src
# dependencies 
install_requires =
    jsons>=1.6.3
    matplotlib>=3.6.1
    networkx>=2.8.7
    numpy>=1.23.4
    pytest-cov>=4.0.0
python_requires = >=3.8

[options.packages.find]
where = src

[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    snnalgocompare = snnalgocompare:main

[bdist_wheel]
universal = 1

[mypy]
check_untyped_defs = true
disallow_any_generics = true
disallow_incomplete_defs = true
disallow_untyped_defs = true
no_implicit_optional = true
warn_unused_ignores = true

[mypy-tests.*]
disallow_untyped_defs = false
```

I verified all other dependencies `jsons`, `networkx` etc. are automatically installed when the `pip install snnalgocompare` is ran.

### Question

How do I include the `lava-nc-v0.5.1.tar.gz` file in the `setup.py/cfg` such that it is automatically installed when one runs: `pip install snnalgocompare`?

Comment: Not possible. Or at least not easily. It is better to explain to the users of your library in the documentation how to install that "special" dependency.

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering how this was dealt with, with respect to safety. Still I would  be curious what the "not easy" method would involve.

Comment: You could "vendor" that dependency into your own library (lots of drawbacks though and not recommended). -- Maybe it would be better if you edit your question to explain in more details why you want to include that dependency into your own library... because that is quite an unusual request, against the current principles of the Python packaging ecosystem. -- The current "philosophy" is that it is up to the installer to decide how to install things (not up to the author of a library), with the default being: "install from PyPI and only from PyPI".

Comment: There is not much more to it than: *I prefer the package to be self contained* and: *I just want it to work when people do `pip install..`*. However, thank you for sharing the ecosystem principles, I will look into those to see why I should (probably) change my mind.

Comment: The other question is why is this library not on PyPI? Maybe it would be more productive to invest time and energy into getting this one library on PyPI... just a thought. -- And then, if your project is an application there might be better ways to distribute this application than via PyPI (but well that is a completely different topic that can not be covered in this question).